# kubeadm throws "command not found" error. What to do?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am new to kubernetes. I have kubenetes and kubelet installed on my linux (RHEL7) system. I want to get kubeadm on my system, but due to the organization's policy, I can't install it via yum or ap-get, etc. 
Now, I am trying to find the `kubeadm rpm` file, which is compatible for my Redhat linux system. This I can install on the system. i found the rpm files [here](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kubernetes-kubeadm) but after running it the following error shows:

> "error: kubernetes-kubeadm-1.10.3-1.fc29.ppc64le.rpm: not an rpm package" for every rpm file.

How do I solve this? Or are these files compatible with Fedora instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @code-ranger, you can download packages from kubernetes repo, and the way to do that is:

The following link is the xml file which lists all the packages for kubernetes:

https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/primary.xml

This has list of all the packages present in kubernetes, search for kubeadm and you will find something like:

[image]

This gives you a link to the rpm package -kubeadm- and you can use that link as follows:

https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/pool/5af5ecd0bc46fca6c51cc23280f0c0b1522719c282e23a2b1c39b8e720195763-kubeadm-1.13.1-0.x86_64.rpm

Note: This links expire in few weeks or days and new strings generated, so it would be good if you download your rpm locally instead of using link directly.

In similar fashion, you can download other packages like kubelet,kubectl etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note, these links are only current as of this date and will probably be outdated (and thus unsafe to use) within a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks you so much for you help. I have already kubectl and kubelet installed on my system. can you please suggest a way to remove them. As i would have to install the versions which are compatible with the kubeadm version.  Considering i won't be able to commands like "snap remove kubectl" as per the organization firewalls

Comment: You can remove package using `rpm -e kubectl`

Comment: Seems the given link has expired. yesterday, i downloaded the packages but has some version compatibility issues with kubeadm. Is it possible for you to share a new link?

Comment: Hi Anuja. I can share the link with you. I just want you to follow my answer so that you can download it without any help. Click on first link find the kubeadm version you want. In it's href location you will find `pool/<somestrin>-kubeadm` replace that in my second link and you would be good to go. If you face any issues let me know I will share the link with you

Comment: I was trying this only. Yesterday, i worked but today it was not. anyways, it's working now. now what happening is, facing compatibility issue in kubernetes-cni->kubelet->kubeadm.

Comment: If you want to install kubernets 1.13.1 then you should use all the packages like kubectl kubelet etc of same version. On which version, you're trying to install kubernetes?

Comment: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:36:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} and kubespray -v
kubespray 0.5.2

Comment: kubectl version is 1.6 which is a very old release of kubernetes and do not have many crucial features of kubernetes. Could you please move all your kubernetes packages to 1.13.1?

Comment: Ok. updated  kubectl to 1.13.0-0 and cri-tools to 1.12.0-0. on installing kubelet-1.13.0, it's showing  Failed dependencies:
        kubernetes-cni = 0.6.0 is needed by kubelet-1.13.0-0.x86_64
        socat is needed by kubelet-1.13.0-0.x86_64.Then if i try to install kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0. it shows " Failed dependencies:
        kubelet is needed by kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64"

Comment: Install it like: `rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps kubeadm-1.10.3.x86_64.rpm kubelet.rpm kubectl.rpm kubernetes-cni.rpm`

Comment: You are great, @PrafullLadha it worked.Thanks a ton. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find links to the official packages for all OSes included RHEL 7 on the docs page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kube*
EOF

# Set SELinux in permissive mode (effectively disabling it)
setenforce 0
sed -i 's/^SELINUX=enforcing$/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config

yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes

systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I can't use this due organization firewalls. Also i have gone through https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/ link. So wanted to have .rpm file to install kubeadm on my system.

Comment: You can download the RPM from that repo and do whatever you want with it.